# case-esac; syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting crazy for an easy case but can't find what I missing.
they told me the next error:

```
name.sh: 21: name.sh: syntax error: newline unexpected (expecting ")")
```

my code is that one (the error is the line of the case):

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    clear
    echo "________________________________________________________"
    echo "1) Encontraren el disco ficheros que contengan un patrón"
    echo "2) Tamaño de un directorio y su contenido"
    echo "3) Exit"
    echo "________________________________________________________"

    echo -e "\n"
    echo -e "Introduce una opción (1/2/3): \c"
    read answer
    case "$answer" in 
        1) 
            ls
            ;;
        2) 
            cal
            ;;
        3) 
            exit
            ;;
    esac
    echo -e "pressiona enter per continuar \n"
    read input
done
```

Comment: The script works fine for me. What version of bash?

Comment: Some goofy character might be lingering around. I copied and pasted this exact code in my editor and executed it. It worked just fine. I'd say, create a new file called test.sh, copy what you have in the question, paste it in test.sh and try again.

Comment: thanks is true it's works

Comment: Are you using Cygwin? Check your line endings.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to re-invent menus. Bash has a built-in command for them: [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3="Introduce una opción: "
select answer in "Encontraren el disco ficheros que contengan un patrón" \
                "Tamaño de un directorio y su contenido" \
                "Exit"
do
    case "$answer" in 
        "Encontraren el disco ficheros que contengan un patrón")
            ls
            ;;
        "Tamaño de un directorio y su contenido")
            cal
            ;;
        "Exit")
            exit
            ;;
    esac
    read -p "pressiona enter per continuar "
    clear
done
```