# Create/delete users from text file using Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I know this question has been asked a lot but I just can't seem to get it working and I'm kinda on the clock, okay so.

I'm trying to make a bash script with a 4 option menu:
1 Add single user
2 Add from list
3 Delete single user
4 Delete from list

Adding and deleting single users I've got working it's just from list that keep defeating me.

This is the code I've got so far

```
#!/bin/bash

choice=5
# Main display
echo "Enter number to select an option"
echo
echo "1) Add Single User"
echo "2) Add Users from list"
echo "3) Delete Single User"
echo "4) Delete users from list"
echo

while [ $choice -eq 5 ]; do

read choice

if [ $choice -eq 1 ] ; then    

    echo -e "Enter Username"
    read user_name
    echo -e "Enter Password"
    read user_passwd
    sudo useradd $user_name -m -p $user_passwd
    cat  /etc/passwd 

else                   

    if [ $choice -eq 2 ] ; then
        x=0
        created=0

        echo -e "Enter file name for users:"
        read user_list

        sudo useradd "$user_list" -m -p "$user_list"

        else

            if [ $choice -eq 3 ] ; then
            cat  /etc/passwd 
            echo
            echo -e "User to be deleted:"
            read del_user
            sudo userdel -r $del_user
            cat  /etc/passwd
            echo

                else

        if [ $choice -eq 4 ] ; then
        echo "Not yet finished"


        else
            echo "#####################"
            echo "# Stop being a noob #"
            echo "#####################"
            echo "1) Add Single User"
            echo "2) Add Users from list"
            echo "3) Delete Single User"
            echo "4) Delete users from list"
            echo
                        choice=5
                fi   
        fi
fi
fi
done
```

The file to get the users from is just

```
User20
User19
User18
User17
User16
User15
User14
User13
User12
User11
User10
User9
User8
User7
User6
User5
User4
User3
User2
User1
```

It's sloppy as hell I know but I just need it for a demo from a presentation assignment, any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you passing the file argument in the "add from list" case as the user's password? See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to safely and reliably read line-by-line data from a file (and other sources).

Comment: I'd suggest using the [`select` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-select) to implement your menus. An example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33159099/7552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read in the name of the file you have to iterate through that file and create or delete user for each line of  the file.

Example :

```
for user in `cat user_list`
do
    sudo useradd "$user" -m -p "$user"
done
```

Comment: Got it working, not exactly how I wanted but it will do. Cheers for the help ivanzg

This is what I got in the end 

`while IFS=: read username fullname password group
do
sudo useradd -m "$username"
done < users.txt`

If anyone else that might use it.

Answer (score 0):

read -p 'add username: ' USER_NAME
read -p 'add password: ' PASSWORD

useradd -m ${USER_NAME}
echo ${PASSWORD} | passwd --stdin ${USER_NAME}
exit 0